# I am implementing machine learning linear regression algorithim i got name error(NameError: name 'names' is not defined)

Tags: python, pandas

When I run this code (in python 3):

```
%matplotlib inline
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.rcParams['figure.figsize']=(20.0,10.0)
url="https://github.com/RupeshMohan/Linear_Regression/blob/master/headbrain.csv"
dataset=pd.read_csv(url,names=names)
print(dataset.shape)
dataset.head()
```

I get:

```
NameError: name 'names' is not defined
```

Comment: 'names' variable isn't declared which you are using in pd.read_csv() function.

Answer (score 0):

The name error occurs if Cpython interpreter does not recognises an object name which have been used in python source code. In your given code you have used at 7th line while using read_csv function

```
dataset=pd.read_csv(url,names=names)
```

you have used names=names but in your code you haven't created 'names' array. names attribute in read_csv() is the list of column names to use. so you need to create a list first and then assign to the attribute names.